# How do I make text added by addItem() appear on QDialog window immediately?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Lately I wrote this program where I have a QMainWindow with a push button and also a QDialog which opens up as push button is pressed.
I also have a [text] (It's written above infoWindow class) and I want that to appear on QDialog word by word, but now It appears all together as my program finishes working.
I've searched a lot but couldn't find what I was exactly searching for.So if you could tell me some ways of making my [text] appear word by word that would be amazing:)))

Here's my code

```
import time , sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from PyQt5 import uic

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTextBrowser


text = ["Lorem ", "Ipsum", " is ", "simply", " dummy", " text", " of the printing", " and", " typesetting", " industry"]



class infoWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super(infoWindow, self).__init__()

        uic.loadUi(r"window_design\info_window.ui", self)
        self.setFixedSize(850, 500)

    def textAdd(self):
        self.show()
        for word in text:
            self.infoList.addItem(word)
            time.sleep(0.2)


class main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(main, self).__init__()

        uic.loadUi(r"window_design\main.ui", self)
        self.info_window = infoWindow()
        self.setFixedSize(850, 500)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.info_window.textAdd)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = main()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(my_app.exec())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GUI systems are *event driven*, meaning that control *must* always return to the application main thread as soon as possible in order to allow proper UI updates and user interaction. Using blocking functions, like for loops and `sleep`, will prevent all that, so the result is that the interface is only updated as soon as the function returns: not only you'll have to wait until all sleeps have expired, but you'll also see only the *final* result (all items shown all at once).

The solution is to use QTimer, which ensures that control is properly returned to the application and functions are executed when required without blocking anything.

In this case, you can *copy* the list and just pop elements from it at regular intervals until the list is empty:

```
class infoWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(infoWindow, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi(r"window_design\info_window.ui", self)
        self.setFixedSize(850, 500)
        self.wordList = text[:]

    def textAdd(self):
        self.show()
        self.nextWord()

    def nextWord(self):
        if not self.wordList:
            return
        self.infoList.addItem(self.wordList.pop(0))
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(200, self.nextWord)
```

Comment: Hi! @musicamante
Thank you for the fast response:))
I've been stuck in this for a couple of days and finally all the information I've read got together.
Really helped me in this thanks :)

Comment: @galaxy you're very welcome. Remember that if an answer solves your issue, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the gray tick mark on its left.